# How does emacs `shell-mode` know to prompt for sudo?

Tags: shell-mode

In `shell-mode`, a command like `sudo CMD` opens up a prompt in the echo area saying:

```
[sudo] password for root:
```

How does it know to do this? AFAIK, this behaviour cannot rise out of simply running `sudo` as usual, because the `read` builtin does not create such a prompt.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is done via a process filter.

By default `comint-output-filter-functions` includes `comint-watch-for-password-prompt`, which is the filter function that handles this.

If it sees text matching `comint-password-prompt-regexp` then it calls `send-invisible` to prompt the user for a password.

For more information about how process filters work, refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Filter Functions`

---

Edit: As a follow-up, note also that you can <kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-quit` and then at the sudo prompt type <kbd>C-g</kbd> to get a backtrace which would show what's going on.  e.g.:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  read-string("[sudo] password for <username>: " nil t nil)
  read-passwd("[sudo] password for <username>: ")
  send-invisible("[sudo] password for <username>: ")
  comint-watch-for-password-prompt("[sudo] password for <username>: ")
  run-hook-with-args(comint-watch-for-password-prompt "[sudo] password for <username>: ")
  comint-output-filter(#<process shell> "[sudo] password for <username>: ")
```

The output is minimal on account of byte-compiled code being evaluated, so the detail of `comint-output-filter-functions` is lost, but you can still immediately see the general situation.  You could also <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `comint.el` <kbd>RET</kbd> to load the uncompiled code and then repeat the whole process to get a more detailed backtrace.

Comment: Great debugging tip!